# c# How to link combobox SelectedIndex to ApplicationSettings

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, applicationsettingsbase

In Visual Studio designer  (I use 2012) there is no way to link ApplicationSettings mechanism to SelectedIndex property (only Text).

What workaround can be used instead?

---

Sorry if my question was against StackOverflow rules. I searched for my question and found no exact answers.

I don't know only how to custom code ApplicationSettings. I always used this feature in design mode - linked Text properties of my textboxes and then used Properties.Settings.Default.Save() to save this and on Form_Load I used Properties.Settings.Default.SomeName to load saved values.
Everything besides this was done by VisualStudio and I don't know what exactly to change its behaviour for my needs.

I was sure that this question would be useful for starting programers

Comment: Sure there is a way and a workaround... it's called programming. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: Can you give a brief example or at least some links?

Comment: No, you show us what you've done so far, and then we'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write some code, it is as easy as using designer, besides, designer generates too much code which you don't understand.

[image]

[Edit Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) in Visual Studio, add a property named "SelectedIndex", set its Type as int, and Scope as `User`, Value as 0 (meaning the 1st item is selected). And you can access this property in your code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboxBox1.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedIndex;
    this.Closing += Form1_Closing;
}

void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedIndex = comboxBox1.SelectedIndex;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```